# Is it haram for a man to look at naked women in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, men-women

Is it wrong for a man to look at a naked woman who is getting changed, if he looks at her without her knowledge?  I require evidences from the Qur'an to support any answer.

Comment: For the sake of clarity, should we assume that the man and the woman in question aren't married to each other?

Comment: This is a legit question, why downvote?

Answer (score 11):

Let alone the naked women, Islam doesn't even allow a man to look into a woman's eyes(with lust). Every muslim is obligated to lower his/her gaze when talking or facing a person of opposite sex.

> #### [An-Nūr (Ayaah 30 - 31)](http://quran.com/14/30-31):
>
> Tell the believing men to reduce [some] of their vision and guard their private parts. That is purer for them. Indeed, Allah is Acquainted with what they do.
>
> And tell the believing women to reduce [some] of their vision and guard their private parts and not expose their adornment except that which [necessarily] appears thereof and to wrap [a portion of] their headcovers over their chests and not expose their adornment except to their husbands, their fathers, their husbands' fathers, their sons, their husbands' sons, their brothers, their brothers' sons, their sisters' sons, their women, that which their right hands possess, or those male attendants having no physical desire, or children who are not yet aware of the private aspects of women. And let them not stamp their feet to make known what they conceal of their adornment. And turn to Allah in repentance, all of you, O believers, that you might succeed.

And spying someone (Watch someone changing without their knowledge) is like eating their flesh.

> #### [Al-Ĥujurāt (Ayah 12)](http://quran.com/49/12):
>
> O you who have believed, avoid much [negative] assumption. Indeed, some assumption is sin. And do not spy or backbite each other. Would one of you like to eat the flesh of his brother when dead? You would detest it. And fear Allah ; indeed, Allah is Accepting of repentance and Merciful.

#### ۚ  وَاللَّهُ عَلِيمٌ حَكِيمٌ (And Allah is the All-Knower, the Wise)

#### اللَّهُمَّ انْفَعْنِي بِمَا عَلَّمْـتَنِي وَ عَلِّمْنِي مَا يَنْفَعُنِي

Comment: "Let alone the naked women, Islam doesn't even allow a man to look into a woman's eyes(with lust). Every muslim is obligated to lower his/her gaze when talking or facing a person of opposite sex." is strictly speaking wrong there are clear exceptions where one is allowed to look at a woman especially when a necessity of recognition is given. Beside you could look at a fiancé without lowering your gaze. What you are not allowed is to keep on looking at a foreign woman, without a necessity.